# New to Regex and very confused

Tags: php, regex

I am new to Regex and very confused, I've read through other questions and still don't understand what to do.

So I have this string:

```
$string = 'hello the image is <img src="wroot/1/15/5.jpg" alt="Image">';
```

And I am trying to get Regex to extract the image tag, how can I go about doing this?

What I've done so far (using preg_match) is a mess so I thought I'd seek out an answer here.

Thanks a lot.

Regards

Matt

Edit:

As per request this is what I came up with.

```
$string = 'hello the image is <img src="wroot/1/15/5.jpg" alt="Image">';
$pattern = '/<img/src="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{24,}$"/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Post the best one you have come up ith

Comment: Hi Ed, I've edited my post for the relevant changes.

Comment: Matt, I've edited my answer to return the whole tag, not just the image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to match html tags like so:

```
</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>
```

Output:

```
<img src="wroot/1/15/5.jpg" alt="Image">
```

See this regexpal link: http://tinyurl.com/k3qqbhr

Answer (score 2):

For this simple instance, you could easily do..

```
preg_match('/src="([^"]*)"/', $string, $match);
echo $match[1]; // => "wroot/1/15/5.jpg"
```

If you're wanting the whole tag..

```
preg_match('/<[^>]*>/', $string, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

Output

```
<img src="wroot/1/15/5.jpg" alt="Image">
```

Comment: He was asking for the whole of the `img` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Matt, is this what you mean?

```
$string = 'hello the image is <img src="wroot/1/15/5.jpg" alt="Image">';
$regex = '~<img[^>]+>~';
if(preg_match($regex,$string,$m)) echo htmlentities($m[0]);
```

**Output:** `<img src="wroot/1/15/5.jpg" alt="Image">`